# how to avoid reset data in selection box, while use Effect in the app do involve reset feature

Tags: reactjs

**Problem:**

Sorry the situation is a bit more than just at it first glance.

I will try summarize the problem in a nut shell, so you get the idea.

In my UI, I have a outcome display and the content depends on two selection box.

So, there are two scenarios in the app

1.Selection box at the top (box 1) and box 2 will determine the content in display

```
// when option is changed, set outcome
 useEffect(() => {
    if (option) {
      setOutcome(() => {
        if (selected === "algorithm" && option === "paper") {
          return algorithm;
        } else if (selected === "language" && option === "tutorial") {
          return language;
        } else if (selected === "dataStructure" && option === "exercise") {
          return dataStructure;
        } else if (selected === "dataStructure") {
          return null;
        }
      });
    }
  }, [option]);
```

2.When the selection in box 1 change, selection box value in box 2 resets

```
// when selected is changed, reset option.
useEffect(() => {
  if (selected) {
    //set option
    setOptions("Choose..."); //I intend to reset it as the value in selected may vary the choices in option in the future.
  }
}, [selected]);
```

**Question from it:**

Everything seems fine until I tried to create a import button that will set the value of the two selection box, hoping to generate the expected display as well.

```
const importHandler = () => {
    setSelected("algorithm");
    setOptions("paper");
  };
```

Expected when I just click the import at the beginning:

[image]

Result: But, when I click import at the beginning, it give me this.

[image]

I guess the problem is in the reset in (// when selected is changed, reset option.), but
I do need the reset in selection box 2, when selection box 1 content change

**How could I avoid such reset when I do the importing?**

**Below is my code**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

/** Function that will set different values to state variable
 * based on which dropdown is selected
 */
export function App(props) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("");

  /** This will be used to create set of options that user will see */
  const [option, setOptions] = React.useState(null);

  const [outcome, setOutcome] = React.useState(null);

  const algorithm = [
    "Searching Algorithm",
    "Sorting Algorithm",
    "Graph Algorithm",
  ];
  const language = ["C++", "Java", "Python", "C#"];
  const dataStructure = ["Arrays", "LinkedList", "Stack", "Queue"];

  const changeSelectOptionHandler = (event) => {
    setSelected(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleOptionChange = (event) => {
    setOptions(event.target.value);
  };

  const importHandler = () => {
    setSelected("algorithm");
    setOptions("paper");
  };

  // when selected is changed, reset option.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selected) {
      //set option
      setOptions("Choose..."); //I intend to reset it as the value in selected may vary the choices in option in the future.
    }
  }, [selected]);

  // when option is changed, set outcome
  useEffect(() => {
    if (option) {
      setOutcome(() => {
        if (selected === "algorithm" && option === "paper") {
          return algorithm;
        } else if (selected === "language" && option === "tutorial") {
          return language;
        } else if (selected === "dataStructure" && option === "exercise") {
          return dataStructure;
        } else if (selected === "dataStructure") {
          return null;
        }
      });
    }
  }, [option]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select value={selected} onChange={changeSelectOptionHandler}>
        <option>Choose...</option>
        <option>algorithm</option>
        <option>language</option>
        <option>dataStructure</option>
      </select>

      <div>
        <select value={option} onChange={handleOptionChange}>
          <option>Choose...</option>
          <option>tutorial</option>
          <option>paper</option>
          <option>exercise</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      {outcome ? outcome : null}

      <button onClick={importHandler}>import</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `useCallback` hook to update on event updates instead of using `useEffect`.

Here's the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pu49gs?file=App.tsx)

---

There are couple of things that are changed.

1. Using `useCallback` hook instead of just using eventHandler function and club all the changes.
   Eariler we had `changeSelectOptionHandler` which would set select as per user selection and later we have a useEffect which sets options to `Choose...` when select was changed. This is a single event action, on a new option selection we have to update the select value and set option to `Choose...`
2. Removing unnecessary `useEffect` and maintaining what is needed.
   Since we had useEffect which would set option to Choose, this was interfering with the selection

Comment: it works , but I dont understand why ? could you explain a bit? you changed changeSelectOptionHandler, handleOptionChange to callback;

Comment: Added description, hope it helps

Comment: sorry for late reply, I have been thinking about it. May I know what is the impact of useCall back here? Is it just for optimization or it's needed to make this work?

Comment: Not only for optimization, but also to have minimal state updates and stopping the unnecessary dependency updates.
Example: Earlier we had callback handler which would update the selection and there is a useEffect with selection as dependency which would trigger. We can have these update in a single place